# Inline a particular function call with LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-c++-api

Given an `llvm::CallInst *`, how can I tell the inliner to inline this particular call. I could mark the target function as `AlwaysInline` and that will inline the call but it will also inline every call. Maybe there’s some way to invoke the inliner on a particular call while I’m emitting it? Inlining all calls within a basic block would work too.

Comment: Could you just create two instances of the function and make one `AlwaysInLine`?

Comment: @WillisBlackburn That would require the calling code to know how to generate the function.

Comment: Although, something like that might work in my situation. I’d still like to inline the call because I think that would be much cleaner.

Comment: Is the function external? I don't think you'll have much luck inlining a function for which you don't have the LLVM instructions. The reason that inline functions in C++ have to be in a header is that the compiler has to be able parse the inline function in the same compilation unit as the calling function.

Comment: The target function and the call site are both in the same translation unit. The call can be inlined if the inliner feels like it. The code that generates the call is decoupled from the code that generates the function. I’d like to keep it that way. Your solution requires coupling two unrelated things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [InlineFunction](https://llvm.org/doxygen/Cloning_8h_source.html) utility present in `llvm/Transforms/Utils/Cloning.h`.
It can accept a `CallInst*` as an argument:

```
llvm::CallInst* call = /* ... */;
llvm::InlineFunctionInfo ifi;

llvm::InlineFunction(call, ifi);
```