# LLVM pass to reliably inline ALL function calls using InlineFunction

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I have an input bitcode file cannot be modified. Say I am looking at a particular function `foo`. I want to inline *all* the calls that `foo()` makes: `bar() -> baz()` and `fez()` and several more.  That is, I want the resulting output to have no call instructions in `foo()`. How do I write an LLVM pass that ***reliably*** does this function inlining?

I looked at the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54339274/inline-a-particular-function-call-with-llvm). I wrote a ModulePass which first collects all `CallInst`s in the module and then calls `InlineFunction()` on them.

```
/* callInstVector contains all CallInsts in foo() */

for (CallInst *ci : callInstVector) {
  CallBase *cb = dyn_cast<CallBase>(ci);
  if (cb->getParent() && cb->getFunction()){
    InlineFunctionInfo ifi;
    auto res = llvm::InlineFunction(*cb, ifi);
    outs() << res.isSuccess() << "\n";
  }
}
```

This pattern seems to work, assuming all the called functions have a definition in the module.

- Is it guaranteed that such an approach could effectively inline all function calls in `foo()`?
- What does the success/failure of `InlineFunction()`'s result depend upon?
- Is this the correct way to go about this or are any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative and more reliable way would be to add the `alwaysinline` attribute to the function, and then rely on the LLVM Inliner to handle the complexities of inlining for you.